Serial killer uses parts of victims' bodies to construct the Vitruvian Man
I'm looking for the movie where, I think, serial killer, who first makes love with his victims and then he brutally kills them. I think he use pieces of their body to make some puzzle, or something like Vitruvian Man. The movie was on TV, 10 years ago. Can someone help me?
I'm not 100 percent sure but I think that killer, with pieces of his victims, makes a pentagram and in the end is something like this 

But in the end, as I remember, the meaning has a connection with picture of Vitruvian Man.. Yes, the movie was on TV, but after midnight.
It isn't Resurrection.

Can you supply any other details. I a very sure that I have seen this but I am stuck thinking "The Bone Collector (1999)" which is not really sexual in nature... ANY OTHER CLUES...

Anamorph also falls into this category. Although I am not sure if he makes a puzzle out of the body parts or not.

Bone collector was the first movie that came to my mind as well, but he didn't have sex with the victims, they were not all women, and he didn't really collect full body parts, just little pieces.

Is it Pieces (1982) aka Mil gritos tiene la noche? From the Wikipedia summary it is clear that the killer makes a puzzle of nude women's bodies after killing them. I didn't watch this film but the description is matching.

I won't downvote this, as I also came across Pieces, but there is no sex involved, and doubtful that it would be on TV in any recognizable form, as it was pretty much a gorefest B movie.

OK, I think I finally found it: Resurrection with Christopher Lambert from 1999. From IMDb:

This deranged psycho is out on the streets of Chicago trying to replicated Jesus' Easter suffering by using unsuspecting persons', whom he kidnaps and brutally murders, body parts in his recreating Jesus' ordeal on the Cross.
Cajun Chicago police detective John Prudhomme, Christopher Lambert, who gets the jump on the killer by deciphering his notes that he carved into his victims bodies he left at his crime scenes. Det. Prudhomme's attempt to catch the elusive killer leads to his partner Det. Hollinsworth, Leland Orsen, ending up not only getting shot by the police, in mistaking him for the killer, but having his left leg cut off, by the killer, when he's left alone and under intensive care in his hospital room!

Here's the tableau he recreates [WARNING: EXTREMELY GORY!], which resembles the Vitruvian Man.
Stephan, I think this is the one you're looking for, but maybe not the OP, because I don't think the killer has sex with his victims (I could be wrong, though). So what do we do now? ;)

A good possibility might be the independent 1994 thriller Cut Up. From IMDb:

Police photographer Carl Roman (Hollins) left his position as a homicide detective after accidentally killing a young girl during a police raid. Four years later, when a serial killer begins stalking New Orleans top retro artists, Carl's friend and former partner persuades him to join the investigation. Enlisting the aid of Mel Korinna, an art historian and denizen of the city's underground art scene, Carl attempts to unravel the mystery of the bizarre, "cut up" messages found at the murder sites.

The serial killer in this film is called The Patchwork Killer because he cuts the victims to pieces and then reassembles them at random. You can find more information about this film here.
